# HTTPS Load Balancing Google Container Cluster

Tags: load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to load balance a cluster that is exposing port 7654.  I've followed the [instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer).  When following it exactly (creating the nginx cluster), it works fine, but when I try to apply it to my containers I can't get it to pass the health check.  If I use kubectl to expose 7654 with LoadBalancer instead of NodePort, I'm able to connect, so it seems that the container is working fine.  Does anyone have any advice for creating a load balancer?

Comment: If you look at the logs for your web server, do you see the health check requests? Are they being served a 200 response? In my experience when the backends are listed as unhealthy it means that the healthchecker isn't able to reach them (usually because of a mis-configured firewall rule).

Comment: The logs show the health check requests.  I was able to make it work by changing the response from the server from an empty 200 response to a 200 response with valid HTML content.  It appears that the health check doesn't only look for the 200 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#overview a successful health check "must return a valid HTTP response with code 200 and close the connection normally within the `timeoutSec` period". It's possible that your empty response wasn't closing the HTTP connection and adding HTML content caused your backend to close the connection.